# Como revisar si HAY conexión con servidor

Tags: java, android, android-studio, servidor, url

Quiero revisar que al abrir una aplicación, revise si hay conexión con el servidor, en caso que no este conectado, mando un alertdialog notificando para después cerrar la app, y si, si hay conexión la aplicación continua normalmente, entonces usando este código es que verifico lo antes mencionado, mas sin embargo no logro que haga lo que deseo.

Lo que hago es utilizar un if al inicio de mi código, que estoy haciendo mal? ó no ocupo los if y puedo directamente validar en el método?
Espero me puedan ayudar, GRACIAS!

```
if(!isConnectedToServer("http://appserver.eco.mx/movil/getLanLong.php",5)){
        AlertDialogErrorServer(Reportes.this.getContext(), "¡No conectado!", "Lo sentimos por el momento la aplicación no está disponible, inténtalo más tarde", true);
    }else { 
   .
   .
   .
}
```

METODO:

```
public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
try{
    URL myUrl = new URL(url);
    URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
    connection.connect();
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle your exceptions
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Quítale el `!` al condicional.

Comment: Ya lo hice de esa forma también, pero igual solo puedo mostrar el mensaje cuando si se conecta al servidor @David

Comment: Quítale el `try catch` y dime exactamente la excepción que te lanza.

Comment: si le quito el try i catch me marca error "unhandled exception" @David

Comment: En ves de utilizar `Exception` utiliza `SocketTimeoutException`.